Binding Dictionary<string, string> to Configuration Section does not work
I'm trying to Bind a Dictionary<string,string> to a configuration section like this:
[TestFixture]
public class When_binding_a_configuration_section
{
  [Test]
  public void should_contain_section()
  {
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddInMemoryCollection()
      .Build();

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
      { "Key", "Value" }
    };

    config.Bind("Section", dict);
    var section = config.GetSection("Section");
    section.GetSection("Section").ShouldNotBeNull(); // true
    section["Key"].ShouldBe("Value"); // false
  }
}

The first assertion succeeds while the section one fails.
What am I doing wrong here?

Bind will bind the data in the configuration (which is empty in your case) to the object instance you have passed to the call (i.e. dict).
Assuming you want to pass the data from the dictionary to the configuration you can do the following:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Section:Key", "Value" }
};
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(dict)
    .Build();
var section = config.GetSection("Section");
var s1 = section["Key"]; // contains "Value"


So there is no way to modify the existing configuration - did I understand this correctly?

@AlexanderZeitler - configuration is "modifiable", but as far as I can see this can't be done with MemoryConfigurationProvider - it copies the initial data (dict) passed to it and you can't modify it. If you want you can write custom updatable configuration provider.

Can you please describe the use case? Do you actually need to modify it?

I want to set up a test host with configuration that can be modified in test setup but with your solution provided I can achieve it anyway. Just need to refactor the host bootrapping.

The existing configuration is a json,so you can use the Json.Net or LitJson and so on to modify it.
